# Error sending mail asynchronously

Tags: c#, smtp

Am trying to asynchronously send an email with an attachment using .net's SMPTClient class:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(MailServer);

                smtp.SendAsync(mailMsg, ""); 

                smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(MailSentCallback);

                mailMsg.Dispose();
```

I need to delete the attachment file from my server as soon as the mail is successfully sent.

```
  private static void MailSentCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           File.Delete(myAttachment);
        }
```

But when this method is called, am getting an error:
"The process cannot access the file 'myAttachment' because it is being used by another process."
Also, mail is not being delivered.If i use Send method instead of SendAsync, then mail delivery is working.

What am i missing here?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all, as mundeep says, connect the event handler before the `SendAsync` call.

Also, do not `Dispose()` the message where you do, because at that point it may not have been 'sent' yet... you're basically potentially corrupting the message while the `SmtpClient` is trying to process it.

Now, as to your actual problem, I had the same problem, and from memory the file is still being held by the `SmtpClient` during the callback, so you really cannot delete it. I think attaching a file in the filesystem is really best only used if this is a persistent file.

If you are trying to send a temporary file, load it into a `MemoryStream`, and create an `Attachment` from that.

It just occurs to me that maybe you can solve the attachment deletion problem by first disposing of the `Attachment` object in your callback handler, before trying to delete the file... although I'd very carefully test that this does not cause other side effects.

Comment: thanks jerryjvl...!am now using Memorystream and attaching it to mail message on the fly....works like a charm without any "file is being used by other process" errors...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should wire up the SendCompletedEventHandler BEFORE you do the SendAsync.
ie:

```
//Wire up SendCompetedEventHandler
smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(MailSentCallback);
//Send the Message
smtp.SendAsync(mailMsg, "");
```

Secondly where is myAttachment declared? What is its scope?